# How do you add line break to JQuery popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I add a line break in my popover content? Neither the line break tag, nor the new line character is working.  This is what I'm trying:

```
$(".foo").hover(function () {
    $(this).popover({
        title: "Bar",
        content: "Line 1 <br /> Line 2 \n Line 3"

    }).popover('show');
}, function () {
    $(this).popover('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to pass the option `html: true` when you initialize the popover. Then `<br />` and other html tags should work:

```
$(".foo").hover(function () {
    $(this).popover({
        title: "Bar",
        content: "Line 1 <br /> Line 2 <br /> Line 3",
        html: true
    }).popover('show');
}, function () {
    $(this).popover('hide');
});
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/twitter-bootstrap/bhtpERLYCo4

Comment: You can also set it as a data attribute in markup like this: data-html="true"

Comment: Thanks! It was really helpful