# Break text to multiple lines in bootstrap popover content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I am trying to add text content of `bootstrap popover` with multiple lines. I am creating string with possible line break as below, I have tried `\n, \r\n, <br>, <br/> and <br />` but all vain.

```
     var files = 'No files selected';
        if (path.length > 1) {
            files = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
                files += path[i] + '<br />';
            }
        }
     $(this).attr('data-content', files);
     $(this).popover('toggle');
```

from above code what input do I get in popover is shown below

[image]

I have read in some posts to add / update `popover` contents through content tag but didn't work. Plus there was a post to set `HTML` content for the `popover` which I didn't get. I don't know what to do to create new lines by using above method or similar one.

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/13338780/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-tooltips-have-multiple-lines        May this help you

Comment: did the trick, thanks! but had to change the css to class .popover-content

Answer (score 32):

You could either add data-html="true" or do that in JS. For the JS solution please refer to [How do you add line break to JQuery popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113476/how-do-you-add-line-break-to-jquery-popover) .

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the option HTML: true when you initialize the popover. Then 
 and other HTML tags should work:

```
$(".foo").hover(function () {
    $(this).popover({
        title: "Bar",
        content: "Line 1 <br /> Line 2 <br /> Line 3",
        html: true
    }).popover('show');
}, function () {
    $(this).popover('hide');
});
```